# Removing dynamic text from a temp file in a script

Tags: powershell

Ok, I know this is going to end up being basic but I cant seem to figure it out. I am trying to build a tool that will allow us to get the full AD group name for a user. The current problem we have is that the names of our AD groups are long, so a `net user MrSmith /domain` ends up truncating the full AD group name. I tried using a `gpresult -user MrSmith /r` but this doesnt return all of the AD groups for some reason.

So I decided that I would create something new that will also have other applications later on. I want to do this by first: doing a `net group /domain` to pull all of the AD groups in the DC. Second run a `net group $ADGroup /domain` for each of the ADGroups in the domain and use that output to search for the specified user ID and create a new output that displays the full name of each AD group that user ID is a part of. I am putting this in a drop down GUI for some of the future features I want to add.

Now I have got a good chunk of the first step done, but obviously I am running into an issue. When I do the `net group /domain` i get output looking like

```
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain MyComapny.com.


Group Accounts for \\Server.MyComapny.com

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*AD_Group_1
*AD_Group_2
*AD_Group_3
*AD_Group_4
.....
```

And I add this to a temp .txt file for use.

The Issue I am having is that its not performing the `net group $Choice /domain` on the AD group selected from the drop down and I dont know why.

Any advice is welcome, I know I am not the best at this so my format and style may not be standard.

```
Clear-Variable DropDownList

$RawADGroups = Net Group /domain >> 'C:\script_out\RawADList1.txt'

(get-content -path 'C:\script_out\RawADList1.txt') | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\*',''} >> 'C:\script_out\RawADList2.txt'

[string[]]$DropDownList = Get-Content -Path 'C:\script_out\RawADList2.txt'


Remove-Item 'C:\script_out\RawADList1.txt'
Remove-Item 'C:\script_out\RawADList2.txt'

function Return-DropDown {
    $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
    if ($Choice)
        {net group $Choice /domain
        }

}

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 340
$Form.height = 150
$Form.Text = "ADGroup"

$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)

ForEach ($Line in $DropDownList) {
    $DropDown.Items.Add($Line)
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

$Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$Button.Text = "Pick One"
$Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
$form.Controls.Add($Button)

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

When I click the `Pick One` button nothing happens, it doesnt reflect anything.

Comment: If you are trying to get all groups the an AD user is a member of, you can do this: `Get-ADUser userName -Properties Memberof ` . If you need the `Name` and not the `DistinguishedName` then you would have to take the DNs and do a `Get-ADGroup`

Comment: We cant use the `Get-AD*` cmdlets as they are not in the basic package and we are not allowed to install mods on our systems.

Comment: What is the value of `$RawADGroups.Count` right before you attempt to do the `Trim`?  Hint: I believe you're going to find it is 0, and if so, the *section around populating `$RawADGroups` isn't working as expected*, and that is where we need to look now.

Comment: I have figured this part out, getting it to do the `net group $Choice /domain` is now the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured this out, it was as I thought VERY simple, I was just forgetting to have the command do anything with the output. Hope this might help someone else.

```
Clear-Variable DropDownList

$RawADGroups = Net Group /domain >> 'C:\script_out\RawADList1.txt'

(get-content -path 'C:\script_out\RawADList1.txt') | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\*',''} >> 'C:\script_out\RawADList2.txt'

[string[]]$DropDownList = Get-Content -Path 'C:\script_out\RawADList2.txt'


Remove-Item 'C:\script_out\RawADList1.txt'
Remove-Item 'C:\script_out\RawADList2.txt'

function Return-DropDown {
    $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
    if ($Choice)
        {
        net group $Choice /domain >> C:\script_out\output.txt
        }

}

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 340
$Form.height = 150
$Form.Text = "ADGroup"

$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)

ForEach ($Line in $DropDownList) {
    $DropDown.Items.Add($Line)
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

$Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$Button.Text = "Pick One"
$Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
$form.Controls.Add($Button)

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```